# How to mass copy folder names in a directory using the terminal?

Tags: bash, terminal, command-line-interface

I have folder A that contains a lot of other folders. I want to copy all the folder names so that I can paste them elsewhere. How can I do that using the terminal?

Folder A
 - folder_1
 - folder_2
 - folder_3

When I copy I should have folder_1, folder_2, folder_3 in my clipboard.

Note: I only want the name and not the contents

Answer (score 1):

My friend just showed me I can do this `echo */ | pbcopy` if I am in the folder A already.